# SqlDataSource and stored procedure call issue

Tags: asp.net, sql, stored-procedures

I've stumbled upon an issue and can't figure it out on my own. Hope someone could help me resolve it.

So, I have a simple stored procedure in a SQL Server 2005 database

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spTest
  @pin varchar(128)
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT @Pin as Param
END
```

and an asp.net page with a `SqlDataSource` and a `GridView` control in an application (VS2008)

```xml
<asp:SqlDataSource 
  ID="sds2" 
  runat="server" 
  ConnectionString="..."
  SelectCommand="spTest"      
  SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"
  >
  <SelectParameters>
    <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="pin" QueryStringField="pin" DbType="String"/>
  </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" DataSourceID="sds2"></asp:GridView>
```

As you can see, the code is straightforward. Nevertheless, if I don't bother specify the pin on the url (`.../Default.aspx` instead of `.../Default.aspx?pin=somevalue`) or specify an empty line (`.../Default.aspx?pin=`) there is no any call to the stored procedure (I check it with SQL Server Profiler).

Moreover, if I replace the `QueryStringParameter` with a simple

```xml
<asp:Parameter Name="pin" DbType="String" />
```

and do not point out *DefaultValue* value, the situation repeats and no calls to the stored procedure are made. What is the reason of such a behaviour?

I'm quite a new to the asp.net and possibly overlook something, but I even tried to do the same in code-behind file programmatically instead of declaratively and the result is the same. The only thing I could find out is that in such case a `Selecting` event of the `SqlDataSource` is fired, but the `Selected` is not. Maybe some kind of an error happens?

Anyway, any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `SqlDataSource` object has a property called `CancelSelectOnNullParameter`.  Its default value is `true`, so I think the behavior you're seeing is expected, albeit not obvious.  Try setting this property to `false`.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource 
  ID="sds2" 
  runat="server" 
  ConnectionString="..."
  SelectCommand="spTest"      
  SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"
  CancelSelectOnNullParameter="false"
  >
```

Additionally, you may find the `ConvertEmptyStringToNull` property of the `Parameter` class (`QueryStringParameter` extends this) to be of some use, depending on if/how your stored proc handles `null` values.  Its default value is `true` as well.

Comment: Jeremy, your advice to set `false` for `CancelSelectOnNullParameter` did the trick! You are right about the attribute! Thanks a lot! Really strange behaviour for the default settings...

Comment: The really annoying thing is that 'trival' examples in the MS documentation don't seem to mention this either

Comment: I think it was working for me for a long time. It's just when I moved my project to 4.5 it stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

1. Create a method which will return db null if parameter is not passed in the stored procedure

   ```
   public static object GetDataValue(object o)
       {
           if (o == null || String.Empty.Equals(o))
               return DBNull.Value;
           else
               return o;
       }
   ```
2. Create a method which will called the stored procedure and fill the dataset.

   public DataSet GetspTest(string pin)
       {

   ```
       try
       {
           DataSet oDS = new DataSet();
           SqlParameter[] oParam = new SqlParameter[1];


           oParam[0] = new SqlParameter("@Pin", GetDataValue(pin));

           oDS = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(DataConnectionString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "spTest", oParam);
           return oDS;
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           ErrorMessage = e.Message;
           return null;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Now bind the dataset to gridview

   ```
   private void GvTest()
   {
       DataSet oDsGvspTest = new DataSet();
               string pin = Request.QueryString["Pin"];
           oDsGvspTest = GetspTest(pin);
               if (oDsGvspTest.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
               {
                   Gv.DataSource = oDsGvspTest;
                   Gv.DataBind();

               }

   }
   ```
4. Now called this method on page_load event

   ```
   if(!IsPostBack)
   {   
   GvTest();
   }
   ```

If found it useful,please mark it as your answer else let me know...

Comment: Sorry AnandMohanAwasthi, but my question is about the reasons of such an odd behaviour rather than about possible workarounds.

Comment: May be it's because, sql server does not accept the null values. In order to successfully execute the procedure even if parameter is not passed you need either declare the Pin null in stored procedure or pass db.null.

Comment: and I forgot to mention that you need to modify the query too. Use COALESCE function.